# Reusing the result of Reduce as a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Certainly a duplicate but under this form I have not found.

The result of `Reduce` here

```
aa = Table[x[i], {i, 3}]
Reduce[{Total[xx] == 3 && cons[[1]]}, xx, Integers]
```

is

```
(x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 0 && 
   x[5] == 3) || (x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 1 && 
   x[5] == 2) || (x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 2 && 
   x[5] == 1) || (x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 3 && 
   x[5] == 0) || (x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 1 && x[4] == 0 && 
   x[5] == 2) || (x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 1 && x[4] == 1 && 
   x[5] == 1) || (x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 1 && x[4] == 2 && 
   x[5] == 0) || (x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 2 && x[4] == 0 && 
   x[5] == 1) || (x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 2 && x[4] == 1 && 
   x[5] == 0) || (x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 3 && x[4] == 0 && 
   x[5] == 0) || (x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 1 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 0 && 
   x[5] == 2) || (x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 1 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 1 && 
   x[5] == 1) || (x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 1 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 2 && 
   x[5] == 0) || (x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 1 && x[3] == 1 && x[4] == 0 && 
   x[5] == 1) || (x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 1 && x[3] == 1 && x[4] == 1 && 
   x[5] == 0) || (x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 1 && x[3] == 2 && x[4] == 0 && 
   x[5] == 0) || (x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 2 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 0 && 
   x[5] == 1) || (x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 2 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 1 && 
   x[5] == 0) || (x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 2 && x[3] == 1 && x[4] == 0 && 
   x[5] == 0) || (x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 3 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 0 && 
   x[5] == 0) || (x[1] == 1 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 0 && 
   x[5] == 2) || (x[1] == 1 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 1 && 
   x[5] == 1) || (x[1] == 1 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 2 && 
   x[5] == 0) || (x[1] == 1 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 1 && x[4] == 0 && 
   x[5] == 1) || (x[1] == 1 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 1 && x[4] == 1 && 
   x[5] == 0) || (x[1] == 1 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 2 && x[4] == 0 && 
   x[5] == 0) || (x[1] == 1 && x[2] == 1 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 0 && 
   x[5] == 1) || (x[1] == 1 && x[2] == 1 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 1 && 
   x[5] == 0) || (x[1] == 1 && x[2] == 1 && x[3] == 1 && x[4] == 0 && 
   x[5] == 0) || (x[1] == 1 && x[2] == 2 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 0 && 
   x[5] == 0) || (x[1] == 2 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 0 && 
   x[5] == 1) || (x[1] == 2 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 1 && 
   x[5] == 0) || (x[1] == 2 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 1 && x[4] == 0 && 
   x[5] == 0) || (x[1] == 2 && x[2] == 1 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 0 && 
   x[5] == 0) || (x[1] == 3 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 0 && 
   x[5] == 0)
```

but I want it as a `Table` composed of element of the type `{0,0,0,3}`. I can do it by a long command involving a transformation in string then many substitutions then a transformation in expression. I wonder if there is not a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Reduce[{Total[xx] == 3 && cons[[1]]}, xx, Integers] /. {Equal -> (#2 &), Or|And -> List}
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 3}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 2}, {0, 0, 0, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 3, 
>     0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 
>     1}, {0, 0, 2, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 3, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 
>     1}, {0, 1, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 
>     0}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 2, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 3, 0, 0, 
>     0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 
>     1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 2, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 
>     0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 0, 1, 
>     0}, {2, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

Answer (score 2):

```
xx = Array[x, 5];
```

Use [`ToRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRules.html) and [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

```
xx /. {Reduce[{Total[xx] == 3 && And @@ Thread[xx >= 0]}, xx, 
    Integers] // ToRules}

(*  {{0, 0, 0, 0, 3}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 2}, {0, 0, 0, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 3, 
  0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 
  1}, {0, 0, 2, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 3, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 
  1}, {0, 1, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 
  0}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 2, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 3, 0, 0, 
  0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 
  1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 2, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 
  0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 0, 1, 
  0}, {2, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 0, 0}}  *)
```

Comment: Learned a new function today. (+1)